# JavaFx WebEngine not rendering properly on Mac OS

Tags: macos, javafx, javafx-webengine

I am using javafx webengine to build an app that renders some webPages, interact with core java functionality on desktop and basically pass info through javascript. Everything works fine when i was developing on my windows pc. I recently imported the project to netbean on my mac pc and on running it, i noticed that the css is not poorly or not rendered at all while everything still works fine on the windows environment. Is there anything I have to do I have not done yet ?

Snippet rendering the webpage on the webengine is:

```
public class WebClientHandler extends Region {

    static WebView browser = new WebView();
    static Preferences pref = Preferences.userNodeForPackage(ServerCall.class);
    static WebEngine webEngine;
    static Stage primaryStage;

    public WebClientHandler(Stage stage) {
        primaryStage = stage;
        webEngine = browser.getEngine();

        if (pref.get(StringRes.productKey, "").isEmpty()) {
            webEngine.load(getClass().getResource("example/welcome.html").toExternalForm());
        } ...
```

Comment: Wich Java version are you using? Maybe try an Update.

Answer (score 0):

The browser JavaFX WebEngine used depends on your OS. 
On Mac OS, User-Agent like this:

> Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0